# DataTemplate Binding for ListBox to ViewModel property

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, styles, datatemplate

I'm using a ListBox with a DataTemplate.

```
                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Order.OrderLines}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">Qty</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding LineQty, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" />

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Weight</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LineWeight}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Pallet Weights</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding PalletWeights}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

The TextBox value is binding properly.  The problem is I have a property on my ViewModel called "ViewMode" which I have the IsEnabled property of the TextBox bound to an App.xaml Style DataTrigger:

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}" Value="Add">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,0,0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,2"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}" Value="Edit">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,0,0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,2"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewMode}" Value="View">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        </Style>
```

This works for all of my other TextBoxes.  How do I get the IsEnabled property to work from within the DataTemplate? The DataContext of the ListBox is referencing the ViewModel property "Order", so I would think it should be able to see the ViewModel property "ViewMode".

Thanks,
-Sid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RelativeSource` markup extension in your Binding in case you want to travel up to the Visual Tree like this -

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ViewMode,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                               AncestorType = UserControl}}" 
             Value="Add">
</DataTrigger>
```

By default `DataContext` for your `TextBox` will be an `object of OrderLine` where is your property `LineQty` resides. So, style is searching for `ViewMode` property in an object of `OrderLine` instead of your ViewModel so you need to use the RelativeSource to explicitly ask it to search it in `DataContext` of your UserControl which is your `ViewModel`.

Comment: Excellent!  Worked perfectly and now it makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

Inside a DataTemplate, you don't get access to the properties from the ViewModel directly (you don't 'inherit' the DataContext).
Assuming your ViewModel is the DataContext of the whole view, you can create a proxy:

```
class BindingProxy : Freezable
{

    #region Freezable Members

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the DataContext from the whole view
    /// </summary>
    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataContextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataContext", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Then, in your XAML file, you need to reference the namespace where BindingProxy is located:

```
<UserControl xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:MyApp.NamespaceWhereBindingProxyIsLocated"
...
```

Later, you create aan instance of BindingProxy for your view and link it with the view's DataContext (notice the DataContext={Binding} part):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <utilities:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Finally, you can use it as the DataContext for each TextBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        ..
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path={TemplateBinding DataContext.LineQty}, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                        ..
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Daniel, I'm confused because the TextBox is binding properly for the value property.  It's the IsEnabled that is not working.  This is part of the App.xaml style which is a DataTrigger.  So is it getting it's DataContext from the ListBox ItemsSource, but not interpreting it for the IsEnabled from the ViewModel?  I'll take a look at your suggestion, it just seems a little counter-intuitive.

Comment: Yes, that's it. In the style, you're supposing that the DataContext of the TextBox is the ViewModel, but when you're dealing with templates, the original DataContext is not 'inherited'. So, even when your ListBox 'inherited' the correct DataContext, the template you are using for its items didn't. So, in order for your style to work properly, you should set the DataContext to what it expects. But when you set the DataContext, your text binding won't work properly anymore, so you have to fix it. I didn't test properly the Text binding, so maybe you could tell me if it works?

Comment: Daniel, I understand now what you were saying about the DataContext.  RV's answer hit the nail on the head with the change to the App.xaml with my DataTrigger to a RelativeSource.  Thanks for the suggestion and your time! -Sid.

Comment: Don't worry. That's a lot easier.. I was just avoiding to modify the style directly and I don't know why :)